# Why do I always generate the same addresses even though I use new?

Tags: c++

I have code like this.

here is my Sayi class,

```
class Sayi{
    private:
            int deger;
    public:
            Sayi(): deger(0){}
            Sayi(int dgr): deger(dgr){}
            int Deger() {return deger;}
};
```

and here my main,

```
int main(){

    Sayi *s1, *s2;
    s1= new Sayi(50);
    s2=s1;

    delete s1;

    Sayi *s3= new Sayi(220);
    Sayi *s4= new Sayi(235);

    std:: cout<< "address of s1: " << s1 << std::endl;
    std:: cout<< "address of s2: " << s2 << std::endl;
    std:: cout<< "address of s3: " << s3 << std::endl;
    std:: cout<< "address of s4: " << s4 << std::endl;

    std:: cout<< "Value of s2: "<< s2->Deger() << std::endl;
    std:: cout<< "Value of s3: "<< s3->Deger() << std::endl;
    std:: cout<< "Value of s4: "<< s4->Deger() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and i have an input like this,

```
address of s1: 0x55db4dc04eb0
address of s2: 0x55db4dc04eb0
address of s3: 0x55db4dc04eb0
address of s4: 0x55db4dc04ed0
Value of s2: 220
Value of s3: 220
Value of s4: 235
```

Here is my question. Why all the addresses are equal? Why i cant create a new address with new and why s2 and s3 equals each other and s4 is different? I expect that s2=50 but s2=220 why is that? Sorry if the questions are silly and for the typo. I am a begginer in c++ and i am trying to understand pointers and classes.

Comment: Note that invoking `s2->Deger()` *after* `s2` has been invalidated is undefined behaviour.

Comment: `s1` and `s2` is same, since you assign `s1` to `s2`. `s3` and `s2` is same, since you delete `s2` and when you allocate another object, the compiler happen to construct it at the same location as `s2`. `s4` is of course different than `s3`.

Comment: @GauravSehgal gave the correct answer. I only add that in your output `s4` look similar to `s3`, but in fact is different!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no requirement that new returns a new address. All it has to do is return an address that's different from any existing object. That's what it's doing in your program.

`s4` is different from `s3` because `s3` is still pointing at a valid object when you create `s4`.

`s3` is *allowed* to be the same as `s2` because `s2` is not pointing at a valid object when you create `s3`. You deleted that object when you did `delete s1;` on the previous line (since `s1` and `s2` are both pointing at the same object).

In other words if you want a different address each time then don't delete anything.